# Navbar doesn't expand (React JS)

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I have a problem with my navbar: I create my js element and copy and paste te code form bootswatch in the render() element. Now I can see the navbar but it doesn't expand in any way. I install bootswatch, bootstrap, react-bootstrap in my code; improt the css file in the app.js file, but no sin of life. And in the same way the highlighted current link opened doesn't seems to move when I change page. I'm working on this language for the first time for a university project, so I'm scared it can create me some problem in the future.

Here's the code:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';


export default class Navbar extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <nav className="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-primary">
                <a className="navbar-brand" href="/">Fastbook</a>
                <button className="navbar-toggler" type="button" 
                    data-toggle="collapse" 
                    data-target="#navbarColor01" 
                    aria-controls="navbarColor01" 
                    aria-expanded="false" 
                    aria-label="Toggle navigation"
                >
                    <span className="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>

                <div className="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarColor01">
                    <ul className="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                        <li className="nav-item active">
                            <a className="nav-link" href="/">Home<span className="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                        </li>
                        <li className="nav-item">
                            <a className="nav-link" href="./Rooms">Prenota</a>
                        </li>
                        <li className="nav-item">
                            <a className="nav-link" href="#">Diventa Oste</a>
                        </li>
                        <li className="nav-item">
                            <a className="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </nav>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: if you want to you click on the link it navigate to to your page ,you should use react-router

Comment: no the link isn't a problem, the not showing navbar and not highlighting the page is the biggest ones!

Comment: Try to import css of bootstrap and botswatch in navbar component an verify the path of file

Comment: unfortunatly nothing change. the path is correct, I have my css and my app.js in the same folder in this moment